# How can I check for a certain suffix in my string?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio

I got a list of strings. And I want to check for every string in there. Sometimes, a string can have the suffix `_anim(X)` where `X` is an integer. If such string has that kind of suffix, I need to check for all other strings that have the same "base" (the base being the part without suffix) and finally group such strings and send them to my function.

So, given the next list:

> Man_anim(1)
>
> Woman
>
> Man_anim(3)
>
> Man_anim(2)

My code would discover the base `Man` has a special suffix, and will then generate a new list grouping all `Man` objects and arrange them depending on the value inside parenthesis. The code is supposed to return

> Man_anim(1)
>
> Man_anim(2)
>
> Man_anim(3)

And send such list to my function for further processing.

My problem is, how can I check for the existence of such suffix, and afterwards, check for the value inside parenthesis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know that the suffix is going to be `_anim(X)` every time (obviously, with `X` varying) then you can use a regular expression:

```
Regex.IsMatch(value, @"_anim\(\d+\)$")
```

If the suffix isn't at least moderately consistent, then you'll have to look into data structures, like Suffix Trees, which you can use to determine common structures in strings.

Comment: Interesting. Instead of using IsMatch isn't there something to just get the value of X?

Comment: @Omega, yes, you need a capturing group in the regex: `@"_anim\(<x>\d+\)$"`. Then use Regex.Match and retrieve the value of the group named "x"

Comment: On Regex.IsMatch(1, @"_anim\(<x>\d+\)$") it gives me an error on the @, it tells me "Expression expected"

Comment: You have to use `Match()` instead of `IsMatch()` if you want to extract groups. Thomas' regex is wrong, plus you don't need to create a named group, you can just use an index. it needs to be: `@"_anim\((\d+)\)$"` - then get the first group in the first match.